# Type Inference for React Component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export interface InfiniteScrollProps<TItem> {
  children?: (
    item: TItem,
    index: number,
    ref: React.MutableRefObject<any>,
  ) => React.ReactNode;
  items?: TItem[];
}

declare class InfiniteScroll<TItem> extends React.Component<
  InfiniteScrollProps<TItem>
> {}
```

Give the above type definitions, I expected the type of `item` in the children prop to be inferred based on the type of the `items` prop. But it is defaulting to `unknown`, even though in the past, type inference similar to this has worked. The type of `allItems` is correctly inferred. What could be going on here?

```
export const allItems = Array(2000)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => ({ label: `item ${i + 1}`, value: Math.random() }));

<InfiniteScroll items={allItems} {...props}>
  {(item, _, ref) => (
    <Box
      ref={ref}
      key={item}
      pad="medium"
      border={{ side: 'bottom' }}
      align="center"
    >
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </Box>
  )}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Comment: [PG](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgElrMbg6BlNHAG34AFHGADOAHgAqLOiAB8cAN4U4auGgAWwfgBMi1APwAuOAApV6q1yQhTMuQBpLVtTV1IAHqeoBXEABG9M7krupEmKbI6DAAdACyvjAoAfxIyJgA8gEAVkgYEijUAJ7yIVYAlHAAvIrRGLH1MAByEB4A3C5wNiBiJnAOtgDaALqd5AC+FBQeaPwoRBrzYmKs7Jw8fBCC0rK2il501LqrTbEAwriQ1Ei0El1sHNQ2vALCopKDCl2KSnBTlHIs3mizQEGoYngKEEe16piU8yC-FMkKgNAA5u04AA3aG+JA+fxBKBYiajabkMEQ+AAQTAYBq5iqtWUXSIMF8UGocAkjw2SFe2343TkYmqSmh-FhYgm8i6ViUZh6jjgAH0VRFmYoJLpgNj5JokIIIDyAPS6-UAqwSU1856bN5yyZAA)

Comment: Seems to be typed correctly. Are you doing something differently?

Comment: @ford04 Thanks, I figured it out due to the playground. In that, you haven't added `{...props}`, that's why it worked. Because the type of props is any, it was overriding the type of `items`. Feel free to add that as the answer.

Comment: I think, you can better explain your mistake than I can (-: .  Your comment seems reasonable as an answer.